# What does "fights to break out over" and "get points down" mean in the two below paragraphs?

Tags: sentence-meaning

1. > We are also very pleased with a new installation of the Go-Kart arena which is 120 square metres in area. Again the problem is the geology; we had to level the mounds on the track for safety reasons. We wanted to enable 5-12 year olds to use the go-karts. And the main attraction here is the Formula 1 Kart. We're known **fights to break out over** who gets it! And the finally to our most recent development which is the landscaped ...
2. > Tutor: There are several study skills books you can consult.
   >
   > Caroline: Right.
   >
   > Tutor: They'll be a good source of reference but the problem is they are sometimes too general.
   >
   > Caroline: Yes that's what i've found.
   >
   > Tutor: Other than that i would strongly advise quite simple ideas like using a card index.
   >
   > Caroline: Well, yes, I've never done that before.
   >
   > Tutor: It's simple, but it really works because you have to **get points down in a small space.**

Comment: Have you tried a dictionary? Did it not help? The idioms you ask about should be in most good English dictionaries ("get something down", etc).

Comment: Regarding #1, it seems to me there's actually a typo as it would make much more sense if it read `We've known fights ...` instead of `We're`.

Comment: yeah we've known. I'm sorry. And the first one, well i dont understand what "points" mean in that context. Could you help me make both of them clear??

Comment: Search online for "point definition" and you'll see that one of the meanings is `"an argument or idea"` (e.g. "what's your point?"). As @StuartF said, these idioms are common and it shouldn't be difficult to find explanations online.

Comment: "break out" means "start".